# TS2304: Cannot find name 'Office'. when deploying to azure

Tags: typescript, azure, webpack, office-js, kudu

I have used `yo office` ([Yeoman Office Generator](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office)) to create a Word addin - using `typescript`, `react`, `webpack`.

When I run it in my dev environment using `npm start` it works perfectly.

When I deploy to `Azure` via `Github` + `Kudu`, compilation succeeds but then when I browse to it, I get the following error:

> ERROR in /home/site/wwwroot/function-file/function-file.ts(12,3)
>
> TS2304: Cannot find name 'Office'.
>
> ERROR in /home/site/wwwroot/function-file/function-file.ts(21,12)
>
> TS2304: Cannot find name 'Word'.

and more of the same ilk...

`office-js` is loaded in my html `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>`

but there are no `imports` in my `tsx` files... I left everything as the generator created it.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Hmm. Can you see if https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/office-js is installed? Or if it somehow got excluded from the build on the server (check node modules) .

Comment: @blackening - thank you for the suggestion. How do I check?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with your setup, but basically you need to check the node modules folder on azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you still need to specify that the office-js types should be used. Open up src/tsconfig.app.json and add office-js to the types array, which should then look like this if it was previously an empty array:

```
"types": [
  "office-js"
]
```

Next, you need to run the command tsc -p tsconfig.json from within your project directory before attempting to build the project again.

Take a look at this link for [reference](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers/issues/82).

Comment: Glad to know it helped. You can create new question and send a question link to me will take a look later.

Comment: Thank you it is very kind of you. I guess I need to write a deployment script as the project compiles but when I ftp to it, I get all my files in `wwwroot` and a `dist` folder within it... I thought the whole thing would just work automagically but it doesn't. :(

Answer (score 1):

add this at top

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/office-js/index.d.ts" />
```